# How to get a random number in FactoryGirl?

Tags: rspec, factory-bot

Is it possible for FactoryGirl to define a random number say from 0-10?

```
    factory :rating do
       ranking 1 #random number?
       recipe
    end
```

I'd really like the ranking number generated to be a random value between 0-10.

I want to generate ratings with different numbers, but don't want to explicitly define them in rspec.  This would be used to display the average and other stats from the rating numbers. Ex: How many 10's, How many 0's, average etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of version 4.4, the following works for me...

```
factory :rating do
   ranking {rand(1..10)}
   recipe
end
```

And for a slightly different use of randomization:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :plan do
    name {["Free", "Standard", "Enterprise"].sample}
    price {Faker::numerify('$##')}
  end
end
```

Creating a few instances, you can see the randomization of name, and the randomization of the price:

```
2.0.0-p247 :010 > 4.times.each {FactoryGirl.create(:plan)}
2.0.0-p247 :011 > ap Plan.to_list
[
    [0] [
        [0] "Free: $48",
        [1] BSON::ObjectId('549f6da466e76c8f5300000e')
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] "Standard: $69",
        [1] BSON::ObjectId('549f6da466e76c8f5300000f')
    ],
    [2] [
        [0] "Enterprise: $52",
        [1] BSON::ObjectId('549f6da466e76c8f53000010')
    ],
    [3] [
        [0] "Free: $84",
        [1] BSON::ObjectId('549f6da466e76c8f53000011')
    ]
]
```

Comment: Good solution, however I would suggest using the sample method in the Array Class instead.
    name {["Free", "Standard", "Enterprise"].sample}

Answer (score 6):

Something like this possibly?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:random_ranking) do |n|
    @random_rankings ||= (1..10).to_a.shuffle
    @random_rankings[n]
  end

  factory :user do
    id { FactoryGirl.generate(:random_ranking) }
  end
end
```

[Reference here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/350?source=cc)

Comment: This works,  I wasn't aware of the generate command.  Looking it up you can drop the FactoryGirl part and just have `id { generate(:random_ranking) }`